# Show on screen when a proposed documentation change has been approved

Tags: feature-request, documentation

1. I was commenting on a proposed change
2. Someone else approved it while I was commenting
3. I tried to submit my comment and was told that I could no longer do that

Better: Show me on screen if the change has been accepted (or rejected) while I am looking at it (whether I am commenting or not). If it has been accepted, I may not want to spend more time reviewing it or commenting it.